# How to sync two folders between two VMs Linux?

Tags: linux, directory

I am newbie on Linux. I have a folder1 on VM1 and folder 2 on VM2. How can I configure as soon as I edit folder1, folder2 changes too.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider rsync (https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

However I am using SCP which is a "secured copy" using my private key like so:
`scp -r -i /home/private_key_file what_to_copy.txt /var/projects/some_folder root@123.123.123.123:/var/projects/where_to_copy_to >> log_file_with_results.log 2>&1`

So my VM2 is protected with a private key (/home/private_key_file) and I'm using user "root" to login. Hope this helps but that would be the most secure way in my opinion.

I would then run that command in a crontab every minute. For instant sync I don't know how to do so (yet), I hope that 1 minute increments are enough for you?

Comment: First, thanks for your answer ^^. I have 12VMs Linux. I want to just edit one folder on one VM, and all left folders changes too. Is this possible?

Comment: Ah sorry, yes my answer is not complete as I only gave the command.
So yeah I would then run that command in a crontab every minute.
For instant sync I don't know how to do so (yet), I hope that 1 minute increments are enough for you?

So make sure you have cron running and then edit the contab by rrunning `crontab -e`

Comment: So yeah, your opinion is we will use resync command every one minute? Right?

Comment: yes I would do it that way, but then use scp instead of rsync to occupy private keys / SSL to secure your servers (if you haven't already)

Comment: Oh, I understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the same folder on the host machine as drives/folders on the VM guests. This means that a write in VM1 writes into the folder on the host and will also show up on VM2.

How to do this depends on the tool that you use for virtualisation.

Comment: That is also a good idea indeed, when you use something like "Block Storage Volumes" that you can then mount to your droplets / VM's. But yes this depends on where your structure ofc

Comment: Can you show me more details? I use Ubuntu. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately no, since I cannot tell what kind of setup you have. But in VMware for example there is an option like "mount folder X as drive in VM" that you would use on both machines. As a folder just create a new folder for that purpose e.g. in your user directory (for a small personal setup, in a production environment probably some other folder).

Answer (score 0):

You can try rsync + crontab

```
rsync /path/to/folder1 username@host:/path/to/folder2
```

you can set this task on crontab using a short delay of time.

Don't forget to put the respectively keys ssh pk into yours VMs ( /.ssh )

it work easy for me.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond rsync as the other answers have mentioned, you can consider mounting the directory on other VMs using Network File System (NFS). The following [article](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-mount-an-nfs-share-in-linux/) documents the steps to installing and configuring NFS quite well.

If you are new to Linux, I would advise for you to snapshot the VMs before making any changes so that you will be able to revert to an earlier snapshot in the event that something breaks.